# "И" в значении "нo". Помогите разобраться с запятой

Tags: пунктуация

**Я ем по ночам() и не толстею.**

Если "и" в значении "но", то запятая ставится, а если подразумевается перечисление, то запятая не ставится?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант 1.  **Я ем по ночам и не толстею** (соединительный союз).

Вариант 2. **Я ем по ночам,  и не толстею** (присоединительный союз с оттенком противопоставления). Постановка тире возможна, но при этом  требуется увеличенная пауза.

**Сравнить**: Она вслух читала романы, и была виновата во всех ошибках автора.

**Выбор вариант зависит от контекста.** (1) Можно поправиться, если есть по ночам? – Я, к примеру, ем по ночам и не толстею. (2) Кто есть по ночам, тот обязательно толстеет. – А я вот ем по ночам, и не толстею.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы подразумеваете противопоставление (Я думал, что тот, кто ест по начам, толстеет.), то, по-моему, здесь нужно поставить тире: Я ем по ночам - и не толстею.

А а если нет противопоставления (Я был уверен, что не буду толстеть, если буду есть по ночам), тогда никакие знаки препинания не требуются: Я ем по ночам и не толстею.

Грамота.ру: 
§ 169. Тире ставится между двумя сказуемыми и между двумя независимыми предложениями, если во втором из них содержится неожиданное присоединение или резкое противопоставление по отношению к первому, например:

Хотел объехать целый свет – и не объехал сотой доли. (Грибоедов)