# Знак препинания перед И в зависимости от смысловой нагрузки

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте,уважаемые форумчане.

**Инопланетный симбионт захватывал людей ()и даровал им силу.**

Запятая ставится в зависимости от того,какой смысл мы хотим передать предложением?
Например:

*Инопланетный симбионт захватывал людей ,и(а потом)даровал им силу.*

*Инопланетный симбионт захватывал людей и(да) даровал им силу.*

Или запятая не должна ставиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Инопланетный симбионт захватывал людей и даровал им силу.***

Запятая в этом предложении не ставится ни при каких условиях, ибо союз И соединяет всего лишь однородные сказуемые ЗАХВАТЫВАЛ и ДАРОВАЛ. Случай совершенно прозрачный, двусмысленности никакой.

Но если Вы хотите как-то выделить вторую часть предложения, поставьте интонационное ТИРЕ:

***Инопланетный симбионт захватывал людей - и даровал им силу.***

Такое (авторское) тире ставится довольно часто для усиления восходящей интонации и обозначения значительной паузы. Только чаще ставится не перед И, а после него:

***Инопланетный симбионт захватывал людей и - даровал им силу.***

Comment: IMHO: Дело не в однородные сказуемых. Даже при однородных сказуемых И может выступать как "присоединительный союз с оттенком противопоставления", и тогда запятая нужна:  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427007/%d0%98-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bdo-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9

Answer (score 1):

**Инопланетный симбионт захватывал людей – и даровал им силу.**

Тире обозначает **неожиданное** развитие событий (что вполне соответствует смыслу) и ставится **перед союзом**.

**Примеры:** Она на ходу посмотрела не него – и отправилась дальше. Я растянулся на сене и уже вздремнул – да вспомнил о «неладном месте» и встрепенулся.

Comment: Симбионт захватывал и даровал. Два независимых друг от друга действия. Может захватить,может даровать. Симбионт захватывал и (и в результате чего) даровал. Одно событие зависит от другого.Разве нельзя "и в результате чего" заменить на "и"?Мне кажется,что в повседневной речи это активно используется.А если можно, то как передать разницу в одинаковых предложениях? Мне казалось,что возможно с помощью запятой.

Comment: Если поставить запятую, то союз будет присоединительный, например: "Она вслух читала романы, и (она) была виновата во всех ошибках автора".   Здесь идет развитие темы (какой-то элемент неожиданности  присутствует, но явного противопоставления и противоречия  нет), интонация как в ССП (пауза обозначена, но не подчеркивается).  В приведенном примере СЕМАНТИКА  глаголов особая: она  не соответствует простому развитию темы (захват - это ожидаемое насилие,  а не неожиданное добро).  Поэтому было бы странно соединять эти глаголы обычным союзом И,

Comment: То есть "и" обязательно нужно заменять на "а потом,и в результате чего,но при этом" чтобы передать зависимость действий?

Comment: Соединительный союз И может выражать как однородные отношения, так и взаимообусловленные/зависимые (в том числе причинно-следственные) при наличии лексики с соответствующим значением, но запятая при наличии соединительного союза не ставится.  Если поставили запятую, то союз И становится присоединительным и  вносит дополнительные значение ОБОСОБЛЕННОСТИ действия - обычно его неожиданный или нестандартный характер. В принципе в этом примере, наверное,  можно поставить запятую (а не тире), надо смотреть по контексту, что больше подходит.

Answer (score 0):

В обоих вариантах нет противопоставления, поэтому запятая не нужна.